# How do I handle Gradle cache on CircleCI 2.0?

Tags: android, circleci, circleci-2.0

We are trying to cache all Gradle dependencies for our Android `build` job.

This is the current approach that is failing:

```
- restore_cache:
    key: android-build-{{ checksum "android/build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "android/app/build.gradle" }}
- save_cache:
    paths:
      - ~/.gradle
    key: android-build-{{ checksum "android/build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "android/app/build.gradle" }}
```

Comment: Define "failing".

Comment: it is not saving the cache, it is always creating again and again

Comment: The cache is working for me using a static key, and I'm saving `.gradle` and `.m2`. Do you really need a dynamic key? CircleCI doesn't explain how the cache works, but there doesn't seem to be anything dynamic in `.gradle` to warrant generating a dynamic key. If your Gradle wrapper version changes, it won't be found in the `restore_cache` step, will be downloaded, and the cache will be updated in the `save_cache` step.

Answer (score 2):

There's a sample Android configuration [by Circle CI themselves here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-android/) as well as a step-by-step walkthrough of the attributes.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/code
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-25-alpha
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
#      - run:
#         name: Chmod permissions #if permission for Gradlew Dependencies fail, use this. 
#         command: sudo chmod +x ./gradlew
      - run:
          name: Download Dependencies
          command: ./gradlew androidDependencies
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command: ./gradlew lint test
      - store_artifacts:
          path: app/build/reports
          destination: reports
      - store_test_results:
          path: app/build/test-results
```

It's worth noting that we experienced some issues when utilising the cache due to submodules, but the above should work for simpler repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Place build steps between `restore_cache` and `save_cache`.

If your project is multi-module/-level **hash all build scripts** and use it as key to proper capture dependencies:

```
  - run:
      name: Hash dependency info
      command: |
        mkdir -p build
        md5sum gradle.properties settings.gradle build.gradle **/build.gradle >build/deps.md5
  - restore_cache:
      key: gradle-{{ checksum "build/deps.md5" }}
  - run:
      name: Build and deploy
      command: >
        bash ./gradlew
        build artifactoryPublish
  - save_cache:
      key: gradle-{{ checksum "build/deps.md5" }}
      paths:
        - ~/.gradle/caches
        - ~/.gradle/wrapper
```

Comment: It is not working fine, the `checksum "build/deps.md5"` returns different key everytime on different CircleCI Jobs. Does it check to create/modify file date?
In other case I don't understand why it returns different keys for the same file content

Comment: @JcMiñarro That means order of files isn't stable or you alter build files each build (like bump version).

Comment: Thanks @gavenkoa
I have review my `deps.md5` outputs and yes, it stored md5 sum on different order.
What I was doing was the following command:
`find . -name "*.gradle" -type f | xargs md5sum > build/deps.md5`
But it return files in different order on every job, so what I did is to sort the find output with the following command:
`find . -name "*.gradle" -type f | sort | xargs md5sum > build/deps.md5`

Thanks for your help